# API Analytics retorna a data incorreta com valores corretos

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Utilizando a SDK do Analytics para efetuar consultas, informo os valores para as `dimensions`, `metrics`, `start-date` e `end-date`.

Obtenho o resultado da consulta com os dados corretos conforme verifiquei no painel do `Anaytics` mas a data é retornada como se fosse do mês anterior.

No exemplo abaixo, passo como parâmetros as seguintes datas conformete a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=pt-br#startDate):

```
'start-date' => string '2016-06-01' (length=10)
'end-date' => string '2016-06-07' (length=10)
```

A consulta `API`:

```
$lastDays     = $this->getAnalytics(
                $viewId     = $this->getDefaultView(),
                $startDate  = '2016-06-01',
                $endDate    = '2016-06-07',
                $metrics    = 'ga:sessions, ga:bounces, ga:goalCompletionsAll, ga:pageviews',
               [
                    'dimensions'    => 'ga:date',
                    'output'        => 'dataTable',
                ]
            );
```

`getAnalytics` método:

```
public function getAnalytics($viewId = 0, $startDate = null, $endDate = null, $metrics = null, $options = null){
        if(!$viewId){
            return false;
        }
        $GoogleAnalyticsAPI = Yii::$app->GoogleAnalytics->auth();

        return $GoogleAnalyticsAPI->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $viewId,
            $startDate,
            $endDate,
            $metrics,
            $options
        );
    }
```

retorna o objeto:

```
object(backend\modules\aplicacao\lib\google\src\Google\Service\Google_Service_Analytics_Accounts)[156]
      protected 'collection_key' => string 'items' (length=5)
      protected 'internal_gapi_mappings' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'itemsType' => string 'Google_Service_Analytics_Account' (length=32)
      protected 'itemsDataType' => string 'array' (length=5)
      public 'itemsPerPage' => int 1000
      public 'kind' => string 'analytics#gaData' (length=16)
      public 'nextLink' => null
      public 'previousLink' => null
      public 'startIndex' => null
      public 'totalResults' => int 7
      public 'username' => null
      protected 'modelData' => 
        array (size=8)
          'id' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=190)
          'query' => 
            array (size=7)
              'start-date' => string '2016-06-01' (length=10)
              'end-date' => string '2016-06-07' (length=10)
              'ids' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=11)
              'dimensions' => string 'ga:date' (length=7)
              'metrics' => 
                array (size=4)
                  ...
              'start-index' => int 1
              'max-results' => int 1000
          'selfLink' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=190)
          'profileInfo' => 
            array (size=6)
              'profileId' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=8)
              'accountId' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=8)
              'webPropertyId' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=14)
              'internalWebPropertyId' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=8)
              'profileName' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=16)
              'tableId' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=11)
          'containsSampledData' => boolean false
          'columnHeaders' => 
            array (size=5)
              0 => 
                array (size=3)
                  ...
              1 => 
                array (size=3)
                  ...
              2 => 
                array (size=3)
                  ...
              3 => 
                array (size=3)
                  ...
              4 => 
                array (size=3)
                  ...
          'totalsForAllResults' => 
            array (size=4)
              'ga:sessions' => string '137' (length=3)
              'ga:bounces' => string '75' (length=2)
              'ga:goalCompletionsAll' => string '0' (length=1)
              'ga:pageviews' => string '447' (length=3)
          'dataTable' => 
            array (size=2)
              'cols' => 
                array (size=5)
                  ...
              'rows' => 
                array (size=7)
                  ...
      protected 'processed' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

As colunas retornadas contém:

```
array (size=1)
  'c' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string 'Date(2016, 05, 01)' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '28' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '15' (length=2)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '100' (length=3)
array (size=1)
  'c' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string 'Date(2016, 05, 02)' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '20' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '6' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '81' (length=2)
array (size=1)
  'c' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string 'Date(2016, 05, 03)' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '31' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '21' (length=2)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '89' (length=2)
array (size=1)
  'c' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string 'Date(2016, 05, 04)' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '20' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '17' (length=2)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '35' (length=2)
array (size=1)
  'c' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string 'Date(2016, 05, 05)' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '5' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '36' (length=2)
array (size=1)
  'c' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string 'Date(2016, 05, 06)' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '11' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '5' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '37' (length=2)
array (size=1)
  'c' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string 'Date(2016, 05, 07)' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '17' (length=2)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '6' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          'v' => string '69' (length=2)
```

Não encontrei nada que indique que houve mudanças na `API`. Há algum parâmetro que deveria ser passado?

Comment: Marcelo estranho isso, realmente! Para efeito de testes, você tentou alterar o formato de parâmetro? tente passar dessa forma e veja se funciona start-date=7daysAgo end-date=today para sabermos se a causa é realmente o intervalo de datas. Em seu painel do Analytics está configurado o timezone correto? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en

Comment: Ocorre o problema também utilizando as nomenclaturas `today`, `yesterday` e `NdaysAgo`, @Mateus. Verifiquei  o timezone e está correto `GMT -3 - MACEIÓ`, fiz um teste puxando valores do mês de janeiro e o mês retornado é `00`

Comment: Para resolver o problema, utilize o valor das datas em formato 'timestamp' (sempre vindo do PHP para garantir que seja carregado com o timezone do servidor), e lembre-se que no javascript, o domingo é 0, Segunda-feira é 1, e assim por diante.  e os meses também são contados de 0 a 11. Então, sempre acrescente "+ 1".

Comment: Um exemplo de saída: `$dtimeFinal = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "2016-02-01");
$saidaFinal = $dtimeFinal->getTimestamp();` se utilizar timestamp, não precisa fazer nada disso. Pois é só comparar as datas. Importante, se as datas forem geradas em tempos diferentes, é preciso resetar os milisegundos:
`DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s.uO", "2016-02-01");`